# How to use setters in constructor?

Tags: typescript

I can not figure out how to use a setter within a constructor, I want to validate fields before setting them, and I want to do that through the constructor, so heres what I am trying to do:

```
class Person {
  private _name: string;

  constructor(newName: string) {
    // this.name(..) gives error, This expression is not callable. Type 'String' has no call signatures.
    this._name = this.name(newName);
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(newName: string) {
    if (newName.length > 2 && newName.length < 10) {
      this._name = newName;
    } else {
      throw new RangeError("Must be between 2 and 10 characters of length");
    }
  }
}
```

So that I can simply do:

```
const George = new Person("George")
```

Comment: You use the setter the same way any where you have to use it `.name = something` will always call the setter. It's *technically* a function but you never need to execute it yourself.

Comment: @VLAZ so `this.name = newName;`

Comment: Also, as a general architecture, it's usually better to separate your validation logic from your data objects,

Comment: Correct, that will call the setter.

Comment: @VLAZ then where should the validation go, what is the point of setters and so on?

Comment: Make a validator class and have it accept and examine a Person object. Then you can have different validators that enforce different rules, when needed. You can even have a [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) validator build up from smaller ones - e.g., one checks the name, another the age, etc. Then you can build up validation on the fly and change just the age validation (e.g., for US check  `>= 21` for Germany `>= 18`). Validation works well as [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setters (and getters) should not be called explicitly. The setter is automatically invoked when you assign a value to the property (i.e. when you do `this.name = value;`):

```
class Person {
  private _name = '';

  constructor(newName: string) {
    this.name = newName
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(newName: string) {
    if (newName.length > 2 && newName.length < 10) {
      this._name = newName;
    } else {
      throw new RangeError("Must be between 2 and 10 characters of length");
    }
  }
}

console.log(new Person('George').name);
```